Как в Java или Kotlin коде сделать для HUAWEI-телефонов переключение на HUAWEI Text To Speech функцию
Т.е. стандартную Google TTS функцию заменять на HUAWEI TTS функцию на телефонах HUAWEI.
Речь идет только о TTS-функции
